# Migrating Prestashop to a new server, caching and Apollo Pagebuilder

Tags: prestashop-1.7

currently I am a bit lost or maybe have just a mental blockade.

The topic for my question is a **1.7.3.3 Prestashop** currently hosted at shared hosting. Due to slow performance and long TTFB I am currently moving it to a VPS running Plesk, hosted on DigitalOcean.

Now comes the Part where I am a bit lost: I copied the files via WGET, dumped the Database and applied permissions (to my knowledge) correct. Shop comes up at the new Plesk-Host under new domain without issues.

As soon as I am trying to enable MySQL-caching I am able to edit the pages with Apollo Pagebuilder, but not save them anymore. At least the changes don't show up at front office. If I switch back to filecache, changes are propagated as intended, but the modules-page in the backend doesn't work anymore (e.g. error 500, can be fixed by removing /app/cache/prod and app/cache/dev)

So, to summarize my issue: If I enable filecache, everything except the module-page works, if I enable MySQL-cache, everything except Apollo Pagebuilder-propagation works.

**What I already tried:**

I have reinstalled Apollo Pagebuilder, but this rather completely breaks my Front Office (means I'd have to rebuild everything from scratch, as the current status doesn't seem to be read properly).

Exported, reimported and "update and fixed" Apollo, not successful :(

Only thing that comes to my mind as a fix would be sacrificing something to the gods, but I'd rather not do that.

**Environment:**

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; Plesk Onyx 17.8.11; Prestashop 1.7.3.3; PHP 7.1.26

If no one had this problem before, maybe someone has an idea on what to delete to just enable the modules in the backoffice. I'd be willing to take MySQL caching as non-available.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer. As the server including cache was migrated, it cached the database-connection as well. (Fortunately it wasn't able to write on the previous DB).

So if ever someone faces the same issue:

**prestaroot/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php** stores the connectionstrings at 2 positions.

Once in: *protected function getDoctrine_Dbal_DefaultConnectionService()* //**around line 670

and once around line 5000. Easiest would be to just search for your previous connection-credentials.

Also you need to make sure that in **prestaroot/app/cache/prod/appParameters.php** the same, valid, credentials are existant.

Hope it will help someone one day.